# Google custom search API sorting result at last 24 hours

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I'm starting with google custom search api, trying to get last 24 hours results of a search.

Look it: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDdmrtvN-d23_uz0xhGPrtq4IWfYq5vc-8&cx=004917413376548330478:iouwc4ammtu&q=michel+temer&exactTerms=michel+temer&sort=date

but i'm getting results with **1 day ago**, **2 day ago**.

I would like to get results with **hours ago**, is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `sort= time` instead of `sort=date` in end of the url

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI, &sort=time will returns empty results.

Comment: Did you get any solution for that past 24 hours google result